# How to put the Syndication Feed Module Icon in theTop Menu

Tags: joomla-3.x, module-display

I would like to place the `Syndication Feed Module` in its simpliest form (only its icon), at the end of the top-menu of a site (`position-1` of the `protostar` template). Unfortunately, when affected to `position-1`, the module appears on a new line below the menu items.
Does anyone have an idea of the nicest way to do that ?
Help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is what I get:
[image: Here is what I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

For you nav element add this CSS:

```
ul.nav{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

For your feed link add this CSS

```
a.syndicate-module{
    float:right;
    line-height: 34px;
}
```

If you want the feed icon to be left aligned to the menu instead of floating to the right change the CSS to this:

```
a.syndicate-module{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 34px;
}
```

Image links for you to see the difference:

[Left Aligned](http://pasteboard.co/1vAiiOcn.jpg)

[Floated Right](http://pasteboard.co/1vApKNJ1.jpg)

Comment: This pulls the icon to the right but it is still in a line **below** the menu. I guess I need somthing that inhibits the `clear:both` that must be at the end of the CSS of the menu...

Comment: Can you give us a link to look at? You may have to adjust the CSS for a couple of elements. I can take a peek if you have a URL you can share.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the CSS to fix your alignment.

Comment: Added to image links as well.

Comment: Many thanks for your help ! It almost works but if narrow the window so as for the top menu to take 2 lines (or if I add enough items to the menu), the RSS icon is pushed down out of the menu, below the horizontal line. Strange... Sorry.

Comment: That would be part of being responsive based on your nav elements container size. Not really a way around that. The only other thing you could do would be to add a menu item to your navigation that acts as your feed link. Assign a menu item class to it and use the feed icon as the background image. This would basically make the feed icon part of your menu, but it would still be responsive to the parent elements overall width. Any menu will go to 2 lines if you add enough items.

Based on your original question however my answer is correct.

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with being responsive. I realized the problem on the original site which has more menu items than the one I indicate to you which was a reduced version. I'm sure it is possible with CSS stuff and will continue to investigate. I will post the solution if I find it. Speaking about creating a menu item, I don't see how to do that. There is no such menu item in Joomla. How to do that ? The URL corresponding to the icon changes depending on the page it is in... I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Thanks for helping !

Comment: You would need to use a menu extension like MegaMenu JS that would allow using a module as a menu item then using an extension like Flexi Custom Code Module to create the dynamic feed link. You can then include that module as a part of the menu item.

I am sure the issue with the CSS is due to the responsive nature of the menu. The screen is only X pixels wide, once you hit that width anything longer is going to create a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Following Terry idea, I finally got it! The idea is to use display:inline-block for both `ul.nav` and `a.syndicate-module` **and** also to give a width to `ul-nav`.
The menu can then have as many lines as he wants, the RSS icon will be displayed on its right.
So:

```
 ul.nav{
     display: inline-block;
     width: 50%; /*to have a menu with many lines, 98% is the right value*/
 }
```

and

```
a.syndicate-module{
    float:right;
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

gives:
[image: The menu with many lines and the RRS icon on the right]

Many thanks Terry, could not have found this without your help !

Comment: Glad I could help.